# Floor function of product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

We have real number $a$ that satisfies $floor(ax)=afloor(x)$ for every $x$ real number. We have to show that $a$ is an integer. So far I've been able to show that $a$ is a positive rational number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $a$ is rational I can say $a=\frac \ell b$ for $\ell,b$ are integers.

Try to prove (if you didn't already) that all integers have the property you said, so $floor(\ell x/b)=\ell floor(x/b)$ now try to prove that $b=1$

Comment: And we get $floor(x/b)=floor(x)/b$. How can I solve it from here without taking x=1?

Comment: @Asix supposed $b\ne 1$, for any integer $x$ that $b$ is not it's factor of, you will have $floor(x)/b$ not integer, this is contradiction because $floor(x)$ can return only integers

Answer (score 5):

Hint:   for $\,x=1\,$ that reduces to $\,a = \lfloor a \rfloor\,$.